# Plot square root in a contour

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two variables x and y. I decide to plot the square root of their difference using contour as follows:

```
x=0:0.1:100;
y=0:0.1:100;
G=sqrt(x-y);
test2 = G;
test2(~(G<0)) = nan;
[C,h]=contourf(x,y,G,'ShowText','off');
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
```

However I get this error : Error using contourf (line 69)
Z must be size 2x2 or greater.

If that is resolved, I want to reach my goal and plot the actual function which relies on x, y and G itself as follows:
Function = 2 sqrt(x) / G * acoth((sqrt(x) + y/2 )/G )

Answer (score 1):

I give an example

```
x=0:0.1:100;
y=0:0.1:100;
[X, Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
G=sqrt(X-Y);
test2 = G;
test2(~(G<0)) = nan;
[C,h]=contourf(X,Y,abs(G),'ShowText','off');
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
```

Input for contour should be 2D array, but your arrays are 1D.

Here, G is complex number. When you plot G, you should plot absolute G.

The result will be like below.

[image]

Regarding your function,

```
H=((2*sqrt(X))./G).*acoth((sqrt(X) + Y/2 )./G );
```